# Why is the search option of the datatable not showing?

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, datatables

I have the following code. I want to have the search option and also pagination in my `table`. But it doesn't work. Here is my script in the header section:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {

                function format(rowData) {
                    
                    console.log(rowData);
                    var childTable = '<tr>' + '<td></td>'
                            + '<td>Brown, John</td>' + '<td>Staff</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">50</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">$2,500</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">$1,500</td>' + '</tr>'
                            + '<tr>' + '<td></td>' + '<td>Smith, Mary</td>'
                            + '<td>Consultant</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">50</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">$2,500</td>'
                            + '<td class="dt-right">$1,000</td>' + '</tr>';
                    return $(childTable).toArray();
                }

                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                     
                    filter: true,

                    'dom' : 't',
                    'columns' : [ {
                        'className' : 'details-control',
                        'orderable' : false,
                        'data' : null,
                        'defaultContent' : ''
                    }, null, null, null, null, ],
                    'columnDefs' : [ {
                        'targets' : [ 0 ],
                        'width' : '10px',
                    }, {
                        'targets' : [ 1, 2 ],
                        'className' : 'dt-left',
                    }, {
                        'targets' : [ 3, 4, 5 ],
                        'className' : 'dt-right',
                        'width' : '100px',
                    }, ],
                    
                    "pageLength": 10
                });

                // Add event listener for opening and closing details
                $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control',
                        function() {
                            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                            var row = table.row(tr);

                            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                                // This row is already open - close it
                                row.child.hide();
                                tr.removeClass('shown');
                            } else {
                                // Open this row
                                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                                tr.addClass('shown');
                            }
                        });
            });
</script>
```

Here is my `table`:

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Billed</th>
                <th>Collected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        
        
        <th:block th:each="element, iterStat  : ${searchResult}">

            <tr >
                <td></td>
                <td th:text="${element.key}"> Name</td>
                <td>1001-01</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>$5000</td>
                <td>$2500</td>
            </tr>
            </th:block>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is what I have added in the header section:

```
 <link
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

The result shows me a table, in which I can see the elements, and if I click on the row, I can also see the nested rows. But the search box and pagination options are not showing.
I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hiding the search and pagination with this setting in your datatable:

```
'dom' : 't'
```

If you remove it, the Search and Pagination appear.

It's not clear what your intention was with the setting, but you can find the documentation here:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom